# AVURLAsset tracksWithMediaType returns no audioTracks for AVMediaTypeAudio in Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, avasset

I am doing the following

```
    AVURLAsset              *audioAsset  = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:audioUrl options:nil];
    NSArray<AVAssetTrack *> *audioTracks = [audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
```

which works fine on a real device.

The problem is just happening in the simulators. I am having a statically added mp3 in the bundle, so the `audioAsset` is properly initiated. But the array `audioTracks` is empty on the simulator (even though the path in `audioUrl` and the `audioAsset` variable is correct and existing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

I've faced with the same issue on a real device as well. The issue is caused by the fact that after initialising asset it doesn't ready yet.

Please have a look at [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW4):

> You can initialize a player item with an existing asset, or you can initialize a player item directly from a URL so that you can play a resource at a particular location (AVPlayerItem will then create and configure an asset for the resource). As with AVAsset, though, simply initializing a player item doesn’t necessarily mean it’s ready for immediate playback. You can observe (using key-value observing) an item’s status property to determine if and when it’s ready to play.

To fix the issue you can try to do the following:

```
AVURLAsset *audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:audioUrl options:nil];
NSString *tracksKey = @"tracks";
[audioAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:@[tracksKey] completionHandler:
 ^{
    NSError *error;
    AVKeyValueStatus status = [asset statusOfValueForKey:tracksKey error:&error];
    if (status == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded) { 
        // The asset is ready at this point
        NSArray<AVAssetTrack *> *audioTracks = [audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
     }
 }];
```

Also it's worth to note that AVKeyValueStatus status can be AVKeyValueStatusFailed in case if audioAsset is not playable:

```
BOOL result = [audioAsset isPlayable];
```